# Determine addAction click for Android notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to use the new notifications interface. I've added 3 buttons to the notifications, and I want to save something to my database once each of them is clicked.

The notification itself works well and is shown when called, I just don't know how to capture each of the three different button clicks.

I'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch the clicks, but I don't know how to tell which button was clicked.

This is the code of `AddAction`(I've excluded the rest of the notification, as its working well) -

```
    //Yes intent
    Intent yesReceive = new Intent();  
    yesReceive.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    Bundle yesBundle = new Bundle();            
    yesBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 1);//This is the value I want to pass
    yesReceive.putExtras(yesBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentYes = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_v, "Yes", pendingIntentYes);

    //Maybe intent
    Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();  
    maybeReceive.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    Bundle maybeBundle = new Bundle();            
    maybeBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 3);//This is the value I want to pass
    maybeReceive.putExtras(maybeBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_question, "Partly", pendingIntentMaybe);

    //No intent
    Intent noReceive = new Intent();  
    noReceive.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    Bundle noBundle = new Bundle();            
    noBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 2);//This is the value I want to pass
    noReceive.putExtras(noBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentNo = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, noReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_x, "No", pendingIntentNo);
```

This is the code of the `BroadcastReceiver`-

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("shuffTest","I Arrived!!!!");
     //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Bundle answerBundle = intent.getExtras();
    int userAnswer = answerBundle.getInt("userAnswer");
    if(userAnswer == 1)
    {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed YES");
    }
    else if(userAnswer == 2)
    {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed NO");
    }
    else if(userAnswer == 3)
    {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed MAYBE");
    }

}           
}
```

I've registered the `BroadcastReceiver` in the Manifest.
Also, I want to mention that the `BroadcastReceiver` is called when I click one of the buttons in the notification, but the intent always includes an extra of '2'.

This is the notifcation iteslf - 
[image: notification]

Comment: that's strange. I don't see any error in your code. If you change the order of addAction() (and the PendingIntent creation), do you still get '2' ?

Comment: In that case it just gives me the last addAction() I called

Comment: I can register three BroadcastReceivers for each of the three buttons, but I really want to avoid that.

Comment: Why don't you use 3 different intents for the 3 buttons and handle them in a single receiver?

Comment: @Mus, that's exacely what i'm doing. I have 3 different intents, and one receiver.

Comment: I meant three different actions.

Comment: In that BroadcastReceiver you can not start an activity ... how then can you redirect that action to an Activity ?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's because you're using [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) with Intents that have the same action

From the docs:

> if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but its replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

When you specify `pendingIntentMaybe` and `pendingIntentNo`, the system uses the `PendingIntent` created for `pendingIntentYes`, but it overwrites the extras.  Thus, all three variables refer to the same object, and the last extras specified were for `pendingIntentNo`.

You should specify an alternative action for each `Intent`.  You can still have one `BroadcastReceiver`, and just have it intercept all three actions.  This would be less confusing semantically as well :)

Your Notification poster:

```
//Yes intent
Intent yesReceive = new Intent();  
yesReceive.setAction(YES_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntentYes = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_v, "Yes", pendingIntentYes);

//Maybe intent
Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();  
maybeReceive.setAction(MAYBE_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, maybeReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_question, "Partly", pendingIntentMaybe);

//No intent
Intent noReceive = new Intent();  
noReceive.setAction(NO_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntentNo = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, noReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.calendar_x, "No", pendingIntentNo);
```

Your receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(YES_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed YES");
    } else if(MAYBE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed NO");
    } else if(NO_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed MAYBE");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt which I need to clear. I am using a simple service class to start, pause and stop service.So there is one image button which will change its image drawable if I click i.e. play to pause image or vise-verse. In the above code you have mentioned mBuilder.addAction which contain a drawable. I am not able to figure it out where is the id of the image?? is it possible to have two drawable but only for one image button.

Comment: I am getting error in YES_ACTION.equals(action) why? how to solve this issue.

Comment: where and how to you set YES_ACTION, NO_ACTION... etc... And what will  the manifist file look like

Comment: are there any guidelines about the action icons? size , color, which are available built in...?

Comment: please update your answer, the `(YES_ACTION)` attribute is not explained.

Comment: YES_ACTION, NO_ACTION and MAYBE_ACTION are constants I guess

Comment: You can just pass strings in place of NO_ACTION, YES_ACTION, and MAYBE_ACTION .

Answer (score 26):

**STEP_BY_STEP**

**Step 1**

```
public void noto2() // paste in activity
{
    Notification.Builder notif;
    NotificationManager nm;
    notif = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.back_dialog);
    notif.setContentTitle("");
    Uri path = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notif.setSound(path);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent yesReceive = new Intent();
    yesReceive.setAction(AppConstant.YES_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentYes = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, yesReceive, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notif.addAction(R.drawable.back_dialog, "Yes", pendingIntentYes);


    Intent yesReceive2 = new Intent();
    yesReceive2.setAction(AppConstant.STOP_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentYes2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 12345, yesReceive2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notif.addAction(R.drawable.back_dialog, "No", pendingIntentYes2);



    nm.notify(10, notif.getNotification());
}
```

**Step 1.5**

> > I created a global class AppConstant

```
 public class AppConstant 
   {
  public static final String YES_ACTION = "YES_ACTION";
  public static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP_ACTION";
  }
```

**Step 2:**

```
 public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppConstant.YES_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "YES CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else  if (AppConstant.STOP_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "STOP CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

**Step 3**

```
 <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="YES_ACTION"/>
            <action android:name="STOP_ACTION"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @amanpreet. How can we use string resource as value of the "android:name" property

Answer (score 11):

in My case it worked for me after adding the intent-filter

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="YES_ACTION"/>
           <action android:name="NO_ACTION"/>
           <action android:name="MAYBE_ACTION"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

here `YES_ACTION` must be `yourfullpackagename.YES`

like

```
private static final String YES_ACTION = "com.example.packagename.YES";
```

likewise you can use `NO_ACTION` or `MAYBE_ACTION`

In BroadcastReceiver you have to use same `YES_ACTION` as declared above,

means in BroadcastReceiver class you can check for custom Broadcast by following

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String YES_ACTION = "com.example.packagename.YES";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(YES_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

note : instead of YES in YES_ACTION string you can use other word also.

Answer (score 0):

***It's work for me***

[See example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwqMy.jpg)

*In your Service*

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {

    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    activityIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0);

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("quotes_copy", body);
    PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTI_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTI_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_logo, "Copy", actionIntent);

    random = new Random();
    NOTIFY_ID = random.nextInt(1000);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());

}
```

*In your Receiver Class*

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("quotes_copy");

    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

*Manifest*

```
<receiver android:name=".Utils.MyReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Make sure declare receiver in Mainfest