# Create notifications with button.in Android?

Tags: android

I want to create a custom notifications with button. Using this notification i need a response from the user thats why i need that button on it. Please help me.

Comment: Any code you tried? This is not a "pls do my homework" place, we will help you if you re stucked with your own code ;)

Comment: @nouseforname : am noob in android programing. am created notification bar but i didn't know how to place a button on it.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350998/determine-addaction-click-for-android-notifications) out