# Android My BroadcastReceiver Class no receive the action send from Notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

In my IntentService class, i create a Notification and assign ID=1213, and the notification will show up once the apps is open.

```
    Intent cancelScan = new Intent();
    cancelScan.setAction(CANCEL);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1213, cancelScan, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNbuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,"Cancel Scanning",pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNbuilder.build());
```

in my BroadcastReceiver class

```
if(CANCEL.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Log.i(TAG,"Received Broadcasr Receiver");
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //context.stopService(new Intent(context,ScanService.class));
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

and, my Manifest.XML

```
 <receiver android:name=".WifiScanReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="CANCEL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I had tried couple times when i click the action button beneath the notification, but the Logcat did not print anything. Which parts i had done wrong? Thank in Advance.

Comment: What is the value of `CANCEL` in this line: `cancelScan.setAction(CANCEL)`

Comment: private final String CANCEL = "CANCEL", variable and value all i using same name. Thank for your reply :)

Comment: Are you also sure that the value of `CANCEL` in your `BroadcastReceiver` is the same?

Comment: Yes, i declare as private static final String YES_ACTION = "com.example.packagename.CANCEL"; that "packagename" i had rename to my project name as well.

Comment: I don't quite follow. I want to know the value of `CANCEL` on this line: `if(CANCEL.equals(intent.getAction())){`. If that is indeed "com.example.packagename.CANCEL" then this will not work, because your actions do not match

Comment: so i need to declare the value of CANCEL in broadcastReceiver class to private final String CANCEL = "CANCEL" also? not private static final String CANCEL = "com.example.packagename.CANCEL"?

Comment: Yes, otherwise your comparison will not work because you are actually doing this: `"com.example.packagename.CANCEL".equals("CANCEL")` which is not equal. I will create an answer

Comment: just tried, it works. Thank you very much, i will accept the answer once u created.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `CANCEL` and the value declared as action ("CANCEL") in your manifest must be equal, or it won't work. Your's don't, that's why you don't reach your if statement. Your receiver is triggered though, because you send a broadcast with the correct action.

To make sure you use the correct values in your code, you can declare a static final in your `WifiScanReceiver`:

```
public class WifiScanReceiver {
    public static final String CANCEL = "CANCEL";
    ...
}
```

So you can also use it in you code when you send the broadcast:

```
Intent cancelScan = new Intent();
cancelScan.setAction(WifiScanReceiver.CANCEL);
```

That way you are always certain that you use the same value. The only one that you have to make sure is also correct, is the one in your manifest.

Comment: Thank a lot, because i was refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350998/determine-addaction-click-for-android-notifications) here