# How to add actions to my notification's button?

Tags: android, notifications

Here is my code for notification:-

```
public void showNotification(String Name, String Rate, int Image_Source, int PandP, int Repeat) {

    RemoteViews remoteview = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SongsListActivity.class), 0);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContent(remoteview)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setTicker(NameD.getText())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(NameD.getText())
            .setContentText(RateD.getText())
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteview)
            .build();

    notification.bigContentView = remoteview;
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.Repeat_N, Repeat);
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.P_and_P_N, PandP);
    remoteview.setTextViewText(R.id.Name_N, Name);
    remoteview.setTextViewText(R.id.Rate_N, Rate);
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.Image_N, Image_Source);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(111111, notification);
}
```

here is my xml of notification:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#2196F3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image_N"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name_N"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="25"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Rate_N"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#F44336" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Repeat_N"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_repeat_white_48dp"
                android:background="#2196F3"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Previous_N"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous_white_48dp"
                android:background="#2196F3"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/P_and_P_N"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_48dp"
                android:background="#2196F3"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/Next_N"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_white_48dp"
                android:background="#2196F3"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Layout of my notification**

now how do i add action to the 4 buttons in the notification so that:-

a) the Pause Imagebutton pauses the MediaPlayer mediaplayer and then change it image to play.

b) the next and previous Imagebuttons call a method mediaplayer(int i)

c) the Repet Imagebutton call a method changeRepeat()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification maybe this help u

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350998/determine-addaction-click-for-android-notifications

Answer (score 0):

For adding listener into remote views

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.someView, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Ok, suppose i added what you said to on of my button which pauses the song.Now what does that pending Intent do.

Comment: Pending intent is triggered by clicking on pause button . 
Pending intent might start receiver or service or an activity depends on  how you get instance of pending intent .

More info :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.someView, pendingIntent);` in combination with BroadCastReceiver and building notification like this:

```
 private void showNotification(){private void showNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this, 1, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // notification's layout
    RemoteViews mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_small);
    mRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title, "playMusic");
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_content, "pauseMusic");

    Intent intentPlay = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intentPlay.setAction(Constants.PLAY_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
            (this, Constants.PENDING_PLAY_CODE, intentPlay, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent intentPause = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intentPause.setAction(Constants.PAUSE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pIntentPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
            (this, Constants.PENDING_PAUSE_CODE, intentPause, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notif_title, pIntentPlay);
    mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notif_content, pIntentPause);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_play)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
            .setContent(mRemoteViews)
            .setTicker("musicStarted");

    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

in BroadCast receiver trigger method you need to manage media player, in my case I have a service bound to MainActivity, so I have connected Main and Broadcast Receiver through interface, when MainActivity's method triggered it manages Service, service manages it's MediaPlayer