# Push Notification with action button is not working

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-notifications

i have used the fcm for notification and its coming correctly, but when i try to add add buttons in notification its not showing.

my code

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Message From Film")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
             .addAction(R.drawable.pp, "Accept",pendingIntent) 
            .addAction(R.drawable.pp, "Reject",pendingIntent)  
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Can we see `pendingIntent` code?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine on lolypop and pre lolypop devices!
Put more code if its possible.

Comment: @pRaNaY ya sure i updated the code plz check

Comment: @Seyyed am tesing in marashmellow  the notifcation is coming, but the button is not showing

Comment: there should be 3 different intents in your case, one for notification intent, second for action accept and third for action reject. you should not use the same pending intent with all 3 of them. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521314/1576416

Comment: @Edgar 
In my test, the notification comes with "Accept" and "Reject" buttons!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to build use method `build()` in last

**edited code**

**Builder**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("New Message From Film")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
         .addAction(R.drawable.pp, "Accept",pendingIntent) 
        .addAction(R.drawable.pp, "Reject",pendingIntent)  
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**notification**

```
final Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: check edited answer. it showing, but you must have to expand notification